# autorun on flash drive when it's connected

Tags: usb

I have a bash script that is on a flash drive that I would like to run automatically when the flash drive is connected to my Pi.

I've seen instructions on how to do it in Ubuntu, but I can't find the system settings that it uses on the Pi, see [How to autorun files and scripts in Ubuntu when inserting a USB stick like autorun.inf in Windows?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/642511/how-to-autorun-files-and-scripts-in-ubuntu-when-inserting-a-usb-stick-like-autor)

How can I do this?

Comment: so, your research didn't result in https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=31&t=199114 or https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=199356

Comment: My hope is to run the script directly from the usb drive.  Using udev I'd have to have a script on the pi that runs whenever a flash drive is plugged in, check the flash drive to see if it has the script I want to run, and then run it.  I'm just looking for a more native way that isn't so cumbersome.

Comment: That is the native way.